# Ember.Select and selectionBinding

Tags: ember.js

Im confused as to why my bindings are not updating

I have a fiddle here http://jsbin.com/izexuq/4/edit

Ive tried not only this

```
 selectionBinding: 'content.selectedObject'
```

but also this

```
 selectionBinding: 'App.PainfullController.selectedObject'
```

Im not sure what im doing wrong.

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your code is successfully binding the selected value, but it wasn't displaying the selection successfully.

If you add a *needs* dependency from your current template controller to the views controller then you can easily display the binded selection. I've modified your example to show it working here: http://jsbin.com/ocesel/2/edit

Comment: It was the fact that is was trying to update the property on a Class and not an instance of. I noticed in most of the examples that people were updating the property on a .create object vs a .extend object. Once i made a controller that was an instance things worked as expected.

Comment: Thank you. I see now how to handle it both ways. I appreciate the help

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Good luck with Ember... Its really such a great framework

Comment: It is. So far I have been really liking it.